# Why are all my subdomains being redirected to spam sites?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, hosting

There is something very strange going on with the re-directs of my website. I'm not sure where the error lies, and I only have a basic understanding of the htaccess file and everything it does.

Suppose that my website is `www.mywebsite.com`. If I browse to a non-existent subdomain of my website, say, `www.mywebsite.com/noexist`, then I am consequently forwarded to some spam site, but with the address still `www.mywebsite.com/noexist`. All the links on this spam site are of the form `http://www.mywebsite.com/click3.php?S7QytarO...`

I have no idea what is causing this to happen, and not even sure where I should search. I can tell you the structure of my website(s) and domains and the main htaccess files, but there's nothing funny I detect in the files. Why in the world am I being diverted to a spam site?

Comment: post your htaccess file?

Comment: Check your DNS settings.

Comment: Check the contents of your 404 page for any unexptected code. If you accept user submissions (comments, blog posts, etc) make sure you are escaping their input to avoid [XSS attacks[(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the many tips by the people here who suggested possible routes, I've discovered that the problem was that my Wordpress blog (which was the underlying system for my site) had been hacked. I've no idea what was causing the re-direct, but this seems to be a well known problem for Wordpress blogs.

More information can be found [on the Wordpress FAQ.](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked)

I decided to fix the problem in a dramatic fashion by completely removing the Wordpress blog from my site (I meant to do this for a while, anyways). This obviously fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure its a spam site, not some page set up by your hosting provider?

In either case, you need to tell it where to go if the page doesn't exist. [This article](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/) explains how to set up htaccess so you can have a custom 404 page.

The gist of it is that you need to add

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Then put whatever you want your page to say in `404.php`.

Also, `www.mywebsite.com/noexist` is not a subdomain, it's just a page. `www` is technically the subdomain.